# e1000e error -3 and UNCLAIMED network interface

Tags: drivers, 18.04, ethernet

I struggle with a network interface setup on ubuntu18.04. 
There are many google answers I have tried all the day long, but the status remains the same: my network interface is UNCLAIMED, and e1000e freshly installed sounds to have issues to start:

I have downloaded and installed the latest BIOS firmware (A22 on Optiplex790).
Right after the BIOS update, I have been able to see the card working, I thought it was the problem, but the next boot the interface was still unresponsive.

Below is a few information:

```
fred-admin@hillsbrad:~$ dmesg | grep -e e100
[    0.063493] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0xe1000000-0xe19fffff]
[    0.083744] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0xe1000000-0xe19fffff]
[    0.083772] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 1 [mem 0xe1000000-0xe19fffff]
[   17.473173] checking generic (d0000000 e10000) vs hw (d0000000 10000000)
[   17.536896] e1000e: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   17.536986] e1000e: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   17.537688] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.4.2.4-NAPI
[   17.537688] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2019 Intel Corporation.
[   17.537914] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[   18.573498] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -3
```

```
fred-admin@hillsbrad:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0200]'
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [1028:047e]
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 04)
```

```
fred-admin@hillsbrad:~$ sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password for fred-admin: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e1a00000-e1a1ffff memory:e1a80000-e1a80fff ioport:3080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1.2
       logical name: wlx002ea6020c5c
       serial: 00:2e:a6:02:0c:5c
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=4.18.0-25-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.41 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 and I found a workaround.

In my case, ethernet network was not working after a cold boot (after a restart, it was working).
The error was the same as yours : `e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -3` and a `lshw -c network` was giving me an `unclaimed` as result for the ethernet controller.

I also tried a lot of thing (updating e1000e driver, bios, change WOL parameters on bios, etc,etc ...) : all of that failed.

As a workaround, I added this line in the `/etc/rc.local` file :

```
rmmod e1000e && modprobe e1000e
```

on a line before the `exit 0`.

Before doing that, you should try to boot normally, and then check if a `sudo rmmod e1000e && sudo modprobe e1000e` makes your ethernet controller work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Same problem, but `sudo rmmod e1000e && sudo modprobe e1000e` not working for me. Is there some news ?